# Get exact width and height of images in react

Tags: reactjs, image, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react.
I have an array of images loaded by [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) plugin. and I map them like this:

```
images.map((img, index) => <img src={img}>
```

How can I get the width and height attribute of each image? I know how I can set the attributes but I don't know the height and width of images as they're in an array.

Comment: The height and width based on what? Like if the page's stylesheet has `img { height: 40px; }` does that influence this value, or are you talking about the actual image size as it would look at 100% zoom? And get it for use inside the `render` function or some time later?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes I need the actual image size and yes I want to use them in render function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could explore using something like [`image-size-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size-loader). `file-loader` doesn't offer the behavior that you are looking for.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Does it give the ability to set outputPath and other file-loader options?

Comment: I also found [image-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size) which is just for getting size of images.

Comment: You'd have to look at the docs for options, I don't know. The loader [uses `image-size`](https://github.com/boopathi/image-size-loader/blob/master/index.js#L2) inside itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can getting data with the onLoad attribute

```
class ImgLoader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: false,
    };
  }

  onImgLoad = ({ target: img }) => {
    this.setState({
      width: img.width,
      height: img.height,
    });
  };

  onImgError = e => {
    e.target.src = '/path/no-picture.jpg';
    this.setState({
      error: true,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { image, alt } = this.props;
    const { width, height, error } = this.state;
    console.log(width, height, error);
    return <img onLoad={this.onImgLoad} src={image} alt={alt} onError={this.onImgError} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

There are many ways, and it's still a debate in the front-end world which ways are best. Here are two simple ways to get you started.

**In-line style**

```
<img style={{width: '50px', height: '50px'}} src={img} />
```

**Simple CSS**

```
import './MyCSSFileName'

<img className="fixed_img" src={img} />

// in your .css file
.fixed_img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Actually my question is that how should I get the width and height